# Enviar namespace xmlns:xsi e xmlns:xsd na resposta webservice soap

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, soap

Tenho um *webservice* desenvolvido em java funcionando perfeitamente, só que preciso enviar os *namespace* `xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd` como mostra no exemplo abaixo:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > </soap:Envelope>'
```

A resposta que estou enviando é a seguinte:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

</soap:Envelope>
```

Se eu não mandar os *namespace* o meu cliente recebe a resposta `null`.

Já tentei por *annotation* e configurando o meu jboss e nada resolveu. sou novo em *Webservice* SOAP.

---

Estou usando o JBoss WildFly e JBossWS com CXF.

Minha interface:

```java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "NOTFISSoap")
public interface NOTFISSoap {

    @WebMethod(action = "http://tempuri.org/receberNotasFiscais")
    @WebResult(name = "receberNotasFiscaisResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    public ReceberNotasFiscaisResult receberNotasFiscais(
            @WebParam(name = "paramNotaFiscal", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
            ArrayOfDestinatarioMercadoriaV2 paramNotaFiscal,
            @WebParam(name = "classAuthenticationNotFis_v2", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", header=true)
            ClassAuthenticationNotFisV2 authentication
    );
}
```

Minha implementação:

```java
@WebService(serviceName = "NOTFIS", endpointInterface = "br.com.ws.soap.service.NOTFISSoap", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class NOTFISSoapImpl implements NOTFISSoap {

    @Override
    public ReceberNotasFiscaisResult receberNotasFiscais(
            ArrayOfDestinatarioMercadoriaV2 paramNotaFiscal, ClassAuthenticationNotFisV2 authentication) {

        // Código
    }
}
```

Usando o SoapUI, consigo consumir o serviço sem problemas. Apenas o *client* do meu cliente não consegue por que ele espera esses namespaces (`xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd`) na resposta.

Abraços

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes sobre a API e sobre o código que você está usando? Afinal, existem várias tecnologias que trabalham com XML e com SOAP em Java, e cada uma faz de um jeito diferente. Isso é importante também para evitar que alguém poste respostas possivelmente inúteis tais como "*é só dar um replace na String que representa o SOAP antes de enviar*".

Comment: Melhorei na a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: Isso daí tem a ver com NF-e?

Comment: Em partes... o meu cliente irá consumir o meu webservice (essa parte está ok) enviando algumas informações, eu processo essas informações e retorno uma resposta para ele... essa parte é que está o problema.

Comment: Os dados tem haver com NF-e... mas apenas os dados... eu recebo dados de destinatários e notas fiscais (regra de negócio dele).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema (não sei se seria melhor saida).

Eu acessei a mensagem no momento do envio através de um "message handlers" e adicionei os namespace.

implementei da seguinte forma:

handler-chain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-class>br.com.ws.handler.AddNamespaceDeclarationHandler</handler-class>
      </handler>
    <handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

Implementação do Webservice:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NOTFIS", 
            endpointInterface = "br.com.ws.NOTFISSoap",                  
            targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@HandlerChain(file="/handler-chain.xml")
public class NOTFISSoapImpl implements NOTFISSoap {
    // Código...
}
```

Meu "message handlers"

```
public class AddNamespaceDeclarationHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {


    private void addNamespaceDeclaration(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

        try {

            if((boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {

                SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();

                SOAPPart part         = message.getSOAPPart();
                SOAPHeader header     = message.getSOAPHeader();
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();

                header.detachNode();

                envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Exception in handler: %s%n", e);
        }
    }
}
```